# CakePHP Migration Errors

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-ec2, xampp

I'm migrating my CakePHP site from a local Xampp installation to an EC2 ubuntu environment. I moved over the DB, and copied the web directory files over to the EC2 instance, but upon accessing the site I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found in /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/CakeErrorController.php on line 31
```

I looked into the Apache error log and found that the piece it wasn't liking was this:

```
$this->Auth->user()['role']
```

The error said the PHP parser wasn't expecting the '['. This all worked fine in the default local Xampp install, so I'm assuming this is a PHP difference between the two installs?

```
Xampp: PHP 5.4.7
EC2: PHP 5.3.10
```

Any idea of any settings or anything that could cause this behavior?

Comment: You can use `$this->Auth->user('role');` to get the value of a specific field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a new feature in php 5.4 see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php the third bullet item.

For php 5.3 you will need to assign it to a variable

```
$user = $this->Auth->user()
$role = $user['role'];
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I suspected, but I wasn't completely sure. Thanks for the link!